# Add Enable Mobile Dropdown

Tags: cms

I add this field to cms Block. Now when I disable or enable this field, it gets updated in the database, but here always show disable. This is my code

```
$form = parent::_prepareForm()->getForm();
      $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('fieldset_cms', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('core')->__('Mobile')));
      $fieldset->addField('is_active_mobile', 'select', array(
            'name'      => 'is_active_mobile',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Mobile Status'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Mobile Status'),
            'required'  => true,
           'options'   => array(
            '1' => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Enabled'),
            '0' => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Disabled'),
        ),
        ));

        return $this;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add another option for ex :

```
$fieldset->addField('your_column', 'text', array(
        'name'      => 'your_column',
        'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Your Column'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Your Column'),
        'disabled'  => false,
        //set field value
        'value'     => $model->getYourColumn()
    ));
```

and then create a method in Model that returns the value from the DB

Comment: but its drprop down as you can see

Comment: can you let here know too how ?

Comment: not getting you

Comment: Thanks i thought above solution does not work :)